# Extract Data into Reload Scripts

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a set of legacy test data on several SQL Server databases which I want to extract in a form that I can replay onto an empty database (with the same schema). I want to do this so that I can manage my test data as SQL scripts (or other script format) in my source code control system - currently the test data created over many years just exists as SQL Server backups.

I dont think SQL Server can extract data in a format which will allow it to replay in referential integrity compliant order - or can it ? Alternatively its there a technical method for doing this that does not require dropping the referential integrity on the destination database while doing the data load ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not quite as straightforward as one would wish, but it is certainly possible - we use the exact setup you describe at my workplace.

In order to generate insert scripts for all data, follow these steps:

1. Open a connection to the database engine in SQL Server Management Studio
2. Right-click the database, and choose "Tasks"->"Generate scripts...". A wizard opens.
3. Click "Next" a couple of times, until you are at the "Set Scripting Options" step. There, click the "Advanced" button.
4. In the list that opens, scroll down to find "Type of data to script", where "Schema only" is selected. Change to "Data only" or "Schema and data" depending on what you need ("Data only" would fit the description in your question).
5. Choose where to save the generated script (if you have  a lot of data, a specified file is probably a good idea to avoid OutOfMemory errors...) and click "Next"/"Finish" as appropriate to generate the script.

Good luck!

Comment: Then you'll have to order the table inserts statements according to your referential integrity

Comment: I'll give this a go, but unless its radically changed, it simply dumps out the contents of the tables as "INSERT" statements. This will fail to replay onto a database with referential integrity constraints turned on. In a star schema database I could make a good job at re-ordering the table playback sequence, but this wont work on a sophisticated relational model.

Comment: In our case, we didn't have to do anything extra to make this work. Inserts are grouped by table, and `IDENTITY_INSERT` is temporarily turned off so that id's can be reproduced. From what I could tell from our scripts, the tables are handled in an order that allows constraints to be fulfilled, but it might just be that our model wasn't complicated enough to cause problems. Regardless, it serves as a good starting point - you're only going to generate it once, and then update it in version control.

Comment: Ok - if its using BCP under the hood it probably just bypasses constraints. I didnt know about this scripting tool in SQL Management Studio so I'm happy to accept it as the answer.

Comment: For the record, SQL Management Studio balked when it tried to do the scripts on my database because of circular dependencies in the structure, however another microsoft tool SQL Server Database Migration Wizard did the job for me. It can be found here http://sqlazuremw.codeplex.com/releases/view/32334. Dont be put off by the references to Azure - it will do SQL Server -> SQL Server as well.

Comment: Ah, then I guess our relationship model was just simple enough for this to work well. Glad you found something that did work for you!